# Will there be an Open Data Protocol (OData) endpoint for every (future) Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, status-completed, data-explorer, api

The [official introduction](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/) states the phantastic [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) to be

> a web tool for sharing, querying, and
> analyzing the Creative Commons data
> **from every website** in the Stack
> Exchange network [emphasis mine]

Does this indeed imply [Open Data Protocol (OData)](http://www.odata.org/) endpoints are going to be a regular Stack Exchange service?

Despite sounding pretty clear already I'm specifically asking for confirmation here with regard to my related question [Are the Open Data Protocol (OData) endpoints considered to be part of the API?](https://stackapps.com/questions/735/are-the-open-data-protocol-odata-endpoints-considered-to-be-part-of-the-api).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OData has nothing to do with the API (at http://stackapps.com); it's a service of the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

And yes, all current *and future* Stack Exchange sites will be featured in the SEDE as they are launched. We might wait a few months to build up enough data (stated another way: long enough to prove they can survive in the wild as public beta websites) for them to be interesting before dumping them, though.

Comment: Does that include area51?