# When will StackExchange sites be available in Data-explorer

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, data-explorer, stackexchange-2.0

When will StackExchange 2.0 beta sites be available to query to Data Explorer?  It would be helpful to building the site to be able to query them.  If they are available now, how can I access them?  If they're not, please consider this a `feature-request`.

Comment: In approximately six to eight weeks.

Comment: It's actually 16 - 24 weeks.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53688/will-there-be-an-open-data-protocol-odata-endpoint-for-every-future-stack-exc

Answer (score 8):

Jeff mentioned in [a comment on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/creative-commons-data-dump-jul-10/#comments) that

> We generally wait 4-6 months until a site has enough data to be useful.

This was in reference to the CC Data Dump.  Since the Data Explorer is driven by the CCDD, you can expect it to take at least that long.

Comment: I was in the middle of typing the exact same answer with the exact same citation.