# When are data posted to Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, data-explorer

When are data posted to Stack Exchange Data Explorer? What is the frequency of data being posted to Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Comment: There is weekly refresh now according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens monthly, at roughly the same time as the data dump is released. (SEDE works on the data dump.) New sites aren't added until they have enough data to [warrant being included](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56300/when-will-stackexchange-sites-be-available-in-data-explorer).

EDIT:
Per [the Nov 2010 data dump blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-10/), the schedule is:

> Please note that it may take a day or two for the SEDE to be updated with the latest monthly data dump.

Comment: See also: last section in the [SEDE FAQ](http://odata.stackexchange.com/faq "The Seedy Faq"): "At the moment it is updated shortly after every Stack Exchange Creative Commons Data Dump. We plan to update the data of SEDE weekly or even bi-weekly some time in the future."

Comment: Huh, I didn't even realize SEDE had its own FAQ. +1

Comment: This month may take a little longer as there is a new XML file to put online, which means database schema changes.

Answer (score 0):

This answer from 2011 says weekly, and seems still to be up to date.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77176/169312 (answered Jan 31 '11 at 4:33 by [Jeff Atwood](/users/1/jeff-atwood))

It also has pointers to places where you can attempt to verify that it is still correct.

As already mentioned in a comment, [When will data.SE get updated data?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data) also says weekly, and is slightly newer (2012).

Also, [Is the Data Explorer now updated weekly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156709/is-the-data-explorer-now-updated-weekly/156710#156710) (also from 2012) confirms this (thanks @double-beep)