# Count of all total edited entries

Tags: support, data-explorer

I just checked with [this query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/409/how-many-edits-do-i-have) with user ID **494543** how many edits I made, but it is not showing any result. On the other hand I have edited more than 30 questions.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data there are as of [October 31st](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) - just before you signed up.  When the next dump is loaded there, you'll be able to see your edits.

Comment: what does it mean?? when will i get letest data??

Comment: @Hasmukh - its updated roughly monthly, a few days after the start of the next month.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69356/when-are-data-posted-to-stack-exchange-data-explorer

Comment: i got that.. thank very much =)