# Data from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer is obsolete

Tags: support, data-explorer, api

I was querying data from https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom using a LINQ query in LINQPAD and found that the data I got back is quite obsolete. I searched for Shekhar-Pro (me) by using a `where` clause on ID 399722 and the data returned was for 8 Jan 2011. Why was the data so old?

Isn't the data updated in real time, or at least frequently?

If not, where can I get realtime data?

Answer (score 13):

SEDE data is updated weekly. Usually on Sundays.

https://data.stackexchange.com/faq

The creative commons data dumps are updated bi-monthly (every 2 months):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

If you need more real time data, use the API:

http://stackapps.com

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/help now says "How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated? The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC."