# Data Explorer doesn't show all of my answers

Tags: bug, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Data from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer are obsolete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77174/data-from-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-are-obsolete)

I composed a [simple query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/115220/my-answers?UserId=684229) to show [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/684229/tomas-t) with titles of corresponding questions, ordered by score. Many of [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/684229/tomas-t) are missing there, for example:

- 6 - [Regular expression to match character repeated three
  times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732852/regular-expression-to-match-character-repeated-three-times/7732899#7732899)
- 3 - [Convenience function for # elements in data.frame, matrix,
  vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741793/convenience-function-for-elements-in-data-frame-matrix-vector/7741919#7741919)

In total, only 240 out of 266 answers are displayed. Where is the problem? Some delay? But why? I'm accessing the raw data in database directly, not some derived data (like rep or badges). Moreover, the "Regular expression ..." question is already 2 days old!

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Comment: Maybe because this is not a very good question; it could have been answered by simply reading the [Data Explorer FAQ](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq "FAQ - Stack Exchange Data Explorer") or the [about page](http://data.stackexchange.com/about "About - Stack Exchange Data Explorer"). It's not as appealing to the eye as other site FAQs (and also a bit outdated, it seems), but it does mention that you're not querying the live database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last update to the database was 10 days ago on October 4th.  The Data Explorer is not updated with the most recent data automatically, it is done manually once every 1-2 months (the last update before this one was August 26th or so).

Comment: A more real-time option is using our [API](http://stackapps.com).

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff, is it possible to compose queries online in a simple way like in the Data Explorer?

Comment: @jonsca, if its updated only 1-2 months (!!!) then I dare to say the Data Explorer is not of much use!

Comment: @Tomas The data explorer is just a convenient front end to avoid having to download and load the massive [data dumps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/), where the data dumps in turn are provided more for things like statistical analysis.

Comment: @Tomas It's very useful for the reasons that Kragen has described.  I think Rebecca's got a better idea.  See the http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/help for the syntax for the API.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Well played, well played

Comment: Well played?  Hm?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff I hadn't even thought of the API when I was writing the answer. Just giving you credit.