# Is the data explorer updated manually?

Tags: support, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Data from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer are obsolete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77174/data-from-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-are-obsolete)

I am finding out the number of questions tagged [android](/questions/tagged/android) per day in the year 2011.

I see data only till November 13.

[Android questions per day](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2238/android-questions-per-day)

Is this because the data explorer is updated monthly and manually by **waffles**?

---

I just found out that there is a 'most recent' update on the right side of main page of data explorer.

[image: data-explorer]

Comment: Yes, AFAIK SEDE is updated manually.

Comment: Every morning, waffles fills two large heavy buckets with data, hangs them from a shoulder yoke, and drudges up 20 flights of worn stone steps to reach SEDE.