# Query returns wrong information about me

Tags: support, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Data from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer are obsolete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77174/data-from-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-are-obsolete)

I'm not getting the expected results when running queries with my userId.
Tried to debug what is happening and created a new query to fetch my personal information:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/60061

The results are not accurate according to my profile information as you can see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/768507/tiago-andrade-silva

Namely Reputation and LastAccessDate are wrong.

What is happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8):

The data on the Data Explorer isn't realtime. The data for Stack Overflow is currently as at 22nd December 2011.

[image]

Comment: Omg... why *isn't* it real-time?

Comment: @Mehrdad Funny joke. It *was* a joke, right? *right?*

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you want real-time information use the [API](http://stackapps.com/)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: lol, no, though I'm glad you were amused anyhow. :P
Barry: Oh good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq) contains the explanation:

**How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**
Data is updated monthly.