# Why is Data Explorer not accurate?

Tags: bug, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Data from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer are obsolete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77174/data-from-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-are-obsolete)

I'm just now exploring Data Explorer (for Stack Overflow) and I wrote a simple query to see how many questions I asked. I get 8 rows as result, but on my Stack Overflow account there are 10 questions.

Why is the information on Data Explorer not consistent with the actual data on Stack Overflow?

PS: I used this query: `select ViewCount, Title from Posts where PostTypeId=1 and OwnerUserId=995822` (995822 is my user ID).

Comment: It is not real-time. Data dumps are posted periodically.

Comment: Data dump every month or so.

Comment: Just wanted to mention the update date is on the [front page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2abo3.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data Explorer doesn't use data that is updated in real time.
Once, its data was updated every X month; now, it's updated every Sunday, at 3:00 AM UTC.

If you look at https://data.stackexchange.com/, you will see when the data was updated last time. For example, in the following screenshot, it says it has been updated 7 hours ago.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/help now says "How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated? The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC."

Answer (score -1):

Read the [about page](https://data.stackexchange.com/about):

> The Stack Exchange trilogy data dumps are hosted at ClearBits!. You can subscribe via RSS and be notified every time a new dump is available.
> ...

Short story, it's not realtime data.

Comment: This answer is outdated and no longer valid.