# Why are my SEDE results inaccurate/obsolete/incorrect/outdated?

Tags: support, data-explorer, faq-proposed

When I use [the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com/), the results I get don't reflect recent activity. Sometimes the data I get back are two months out of date. What's wrong?

*This is intended to be a canonical reference for questions about SEDE not reflecting real-time results.*

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 14):

SEDE does not query the production database in real time. It queries a data dump that is  [updated weekly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data/145732#145732).

Updates used to be [monthly, and manual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77176/131713). For real-time data, Jeff suggests using the API; see [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) for more information about that.

Note that the SEDE data dump is not the same thing as the Creative Commons data dumps.

Comment: Why isn't it updated more often? I presume you do database backups; restoring the backups should be part of the process to ensure that the backups are usable and complete. Couldn't those restorations power the SEDE site?

Comment: @MarkRansom SEDE's data are not an exact snapshot of the live data, for example votes are anonymized before the data find their way into SEDE.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast, you could probably achieve that by exposing views rather than the raw tables.