# Does voting to close as duplicate erase earlier comments?

Tags: bug, comments, duplicate-questions, deleted-comments

The first comment on the following question pointed out a previous question and declared that is was similar but not a duplicate.

[Are there any implementations of C++ that don't use vtables and vptrs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388433/are-there-any-implementations-of-c-that-dont-use-vtables-and-vptrs#comment13397602_10388433)

I responded to the comment, and shortly thereafter the question was closed with a completely different link as a duplicate.

The first comment disappeared, and I thought it was because the owner had deleted it. Later they claim they had *not* deleted it, so I suspect a bug in the process that closes a question as a duplicate.

Comment: My original comment said something along the lines of "not a duplicate, but related anyway: (link)". It looks to me like the auto comment deletion process that ran at the time of the edit deleted anything with "duplicate" in the text. (I can't prove that of course, but I was just about to ask the very same question). So by the time the question got closed I had two comments on it, one manual "not a duplicate" and one automatic "possible duplicate". I found the first question I manually posted a link to whilst trying to find the one I remembered seeing.

Comment: @awoodland, I tried to use data.stackexchange.com to find the exact comment text but the question isn't there yet. I presume they use a delayed version of the database.

Comment: data.stackexchange is normally a few months behind and even then it only carries publicly visible information at the time of the dump.

Comment: @awoodland, months behind? Ouch. I thought maybe they would refresh it from a daily backup.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Coincidentally, Popular Demand posted a CW about this just a few minutes ago: [Why are my SEDE results inaccurate/obsolete/incorrect/outdated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130856). According to it, *the team tries to update the SEDE data dump monthly, but that information is almost a year and a half old as of this writing.*

Comment: Related: [Closing as duplicate removes links that point to other duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89279)

Comment: Oh, interesting... the automatic comment wasn't created now. So if there's already a comment with a link to the dupe + the word 'duplicate' a second comment is not created (I always thought that only a second automatic comment is not created). So most probably awoodland voted to close first, creating the automatic link and then the manual "not a duplicate" comment

Comment: @TimStone - my comment explicitly said "not a duplicate" and was never used in the voting as far as I can tell. It played no role in the process other than being deleted. That's awfully confusing if it's "as designed".

Comment: @awoodland Yeah, that doesn't sound right...

Comment: @yoda - the manual "not a duplicate" comment was added by me, first (i.e. before I found the Q I was looking for). The auto duplicate comment was still added when I found it and voted slightly later, it was never edited and nothing interfered with the automatic comment.

Comment: @yoda - forgot to add that the two comments linked to completely different questions.

Comment: @awoodland Interesting... definitely something seems off.