# Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, automatic-comments, duplicate-questions

A user just posted his question a second time here on meta after the first was closed as a duplicate. I wrote a comment on the second post, explaining that the answer to his question is in the linked duplicate and that he shouldn't circumvent the closure process by asking a second identical question.

When the second post was closed as a duplicate my comment was automatically deleted. As far as I understand this is a heuristic that removes obsolete comments, which it considers *every* comment that contains a link to one of the duplicates.

This heuristic is too aggressive and removes comments that go beyond "Duplicate here: link". I suggest that it should be changed to only remove the default duplicate comment, and not any comment that was edited by the owner nor any free-form comment that happens to include a link to the duplicate.

This also triggers for any comment that contains the word "duplicate" **and link to any question**, not only the question being chosen as duplicate, which makes this much worse.

Comment: Agreed. For a long time I thought that even edited *auto comments* were not deleted, but then when wondering about the same, I read [Jeff's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47443/do-not-delete-edited-vote-to-close-auto-comments/47446#47446): *"If you don't want the comment deleted, make sure it doesn't begin with "possible duplicate of"*.

Comment: @Arjan I don't think I put that in front, I wrote the comment first and then voted to close as duplicate. I think the heuristic is even more aggressive than Jeff says.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just edited "even" and "auto" into my comment. I fully agree with what you're asking, and I think I've seen what you're describing too. But then: I often question my own memory ;-)

Comment: Same happened to me [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142069/please-avoid-discussion-go-to-chat), where I did not vote to close, but did post a comment that linked to what became the duplicate. I did use the word "duplicate" though.

Comment: Ah, it seems this has changed: even an edited "possible duplicate" auto-comment was not deleted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143222/how-to-know-when-someone-answer-or-comment). ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PbjSE.png)) Though [elsewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143214/resolved-attributes-for-accepted-answer-question) a manual comment (screenshot [before](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LHXts.png), [after](http://i.stack.imgur.com/m8mnL.png)) was deleted, but maybe by its author.

Comment: Ah, the author of the 2nd comment confirmed it was deleted manually. So, it seems things are resolved indeed.

Comment: Twice in the past few days I've seen my customized comments removed that just happened to contain a link to the duplicate. Just now, I had composed the comment _first_, `Yadda yadda yadda. This is [a duplicate](link://to.duplicate). And so on and so forth.` and _then_ voted to close. The comment no longer exists, although it had other information which is referred to further along in the thread. This is broken, either again or still. The more recent one was immediately before [this comment](http://goo.gl/WzrCC).

Comment: @Josh, it seems this was fixed. That is: even an *auto-comment* of mine was left untouched when a question was closed, so *I assume* manual comments are no longer deleted either.

Comment: It [might](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47443/do-not-delete-edited-vote-to-close-auto-comments/47446#comment474087_47446) still only apply to *edited* comments. (Which is fine for this feature request, but might not solve the issue @Josh and myself were seeing earlier with our own comments that also happened to reference the same duplicate post.)

Comment: And @Josh commented Jan 27 on my deleted answer: *Not sure what's going on, but I've once again had an edited "possible duplicate of <auto-inserted-link>, <link I added>, <link I added>, <link I added>" comment deleted just now. This seems to just be a buggy situation to me. Comment was here: stackoverflow.com/questions/14551665 (I've manually re-posted the other links.)*

Comment: I swear this keeps bouncing back and forth between happening and not happening. This week, it is, and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Today, I started a question that seemed to be a duplicate of this one, har har. I don't understand why anyone would even want the comments to be removed. Do we remove comments requiring clarification after the question was edited? Do they take up too much database space? Is a comment containing a link that is _later_ edited into the question ... duplicate?

Comment: For reference: in April 2010 [Jeff wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47443/do-not-delete-edited/47446#47446) *If you don't want the comment deleted, make sure it doesn't begin with "possible duplicate of"* and [also](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46799/automatic-possible-duplicate-links-are-removed-even-if-the-question-isnt-clos#comment114411_47208) *OK, the "possible duplicate of..." comments are only deleted now in the case where the question was closed as a duplicate. They are also not deleted if they have a non-null EditCount (that is, the little pencil icon).*

Comment: Ah, just had a 100% manual comment deleted again ([here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189972/shouldnt-badges-like-beta-and-area-51-be-removed-if-they-can-no-longer-be-award)). It included two URLs, one of which I also used to vote to close *after* posting that comment. It did not hold the text "possible duplicate of", but did include the word "duplicate". (I even made a screenshot, but was stupid enough to have lost that when the question was eventually closed. One can still [see the other URL in the linked section](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FNL5l.png) though.)

Comment: And again I'm not sure about myself, or I'm seeing the same randomness @Josh reported. My previous comment was backed by the other URL [still being shown](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FNL5l.png) in the linked section (not anymore right now). And meanwhile a developer [has confirmed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s2M5B.png) that my comment was deleted by Community upon closure. But: not so much [in another question which I voted to close today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189967), where my 100% manual (upvoted & edited) comment [is still there after closure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X9dfE.png)...

Comment: On TeX.SX (Aug 29, 2013), I flagged [a question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130693/29288) as a duplicate (since I don't have the rep there to cast a close vote), and edited the comment to explain how the answer applied to the duplicate question, but it was deleted.  I [asked about it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3786/29288) on TeX meta, and came here when I learned that it's network wide.  It started with "Possible duplicate of…", I suppose, but it should have had a non-zero edit count, since I edited it.

Comment: Just as another bit of anecdata to support this request, there's a feature request on MSO, [“This question already has an answer here” banner too easy to miss](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267318/1281433) that points out that people **will** read the comments and still miss the duplicate banner at top.  By deleting these comments, the system is making it *harder* for people to find the duplicate, even when only the standard "possible duplicate of …" comment is deleted.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if there was a facility for undeleting these comments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sooooo turns out the logic for this was explicitly excluding things from deletion which had any edits. Anything that started with our prefix and had the link, by community, **which weren't edited** were removed.

All good, right?

Nope, then a regex ran looking for effectively "duplicate..." and deleted the thing anyway since the prefix is "Possible duplicate of:".

I just fixed that check to exclude `EditCount > 0` as well in the next deploy. This shouldn't happen to edited comments anymore after it goes out today.

Comment: What about the part where it doesn't check whether all linked questions are among the "official" duplicates? Because if any of them aren't, the link (and thus the comment) should not be deleted automatically.

Comment: Honestly it seems like it should only trigger on the exact form of auto-generated comments *relating to an official duplicate*. Any additional/different text should probably be left for humans to deal with.  And that's assuming that auto-deleting these comments upon closure even a good idea in the first place: maybe just don't auto-generate more than one (non-deleted) comment linking to the same question?

Answer (score 64):

To merge something else in here; it's worse than you describe. *Any* comment that contains the word "duplicate" and a link to another question is deleted when a question is closed. This might be solely comments that are owned by someone who voted but I'm unable to test.

It doesn't matter if the comment is *anything* to do with any of the questions that the question in question is being closed as a duplicate of. Flexo's comment to [Does voting to close as duplicate erase earlier comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130864/does-voting-to-close-as-duplicate-erase-earlier-comments) would indicate that this has been happening for a while.

I had two comments on [Subtract boolean from float in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601484/subtract-boolean-from-float-in-python) deleted. One was an unmodified auto-generated possible duplicate comment. The other indicated a potential alternate duplicate; something along the lines of:

> A better duplicate might be [Is it guaranteed that False “is 0” and True “is 1”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263942/is-it-guaranteed-that-false-is-0-and-true-is-1?lq=1) but it was closed as a duplicate of the first question

I've done some science. It seems that the word "duplicate" is not enough; I wrote *"duplicate test comment"* on [java.concurrent.ReentrantLock - why we want to acquire the same lock multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596080/java-concurrent-reentrantlock-why-we-want-to-acquire-the-same-lock-multiple-ti) but it didn't get deleted (I did it manually).

However, on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593792/how-to-lock-excel-cell-using-jxl-api I wrote *"possible duplicate test comment [test](some question)"*, this comment was deleted.

**This shouldn't happen. Comments pointing out separate linkages can be incredibly useful and make the web<sup>1</sup> a better place.**

<sub>1. Pun intended; please tell me someone noticed ;-)?</sub>

Comment: I noticed........after I read there was a pun.

Comment: It's flaky like the county fair's blue ribbon pie crust. Thanks for doing some deliberate testing.

Comment: Yep, just happened to me too [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202421/i-have-to-write-i-have-tried-when-i-ask-something). I did NOT vote to close.

Comment: And happened to me [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167591/why-was-my-comment-auto-deleted). It contained the phrase "possible duplicate" but only in the context "I don't think any of the solutions in the possible duplicate will work for you"

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495501/how-can-i-draw-a-rotated-string-in-2d) I added the "possible duplicate" comment myself, after I voted, as none appeared after my vote. Maybe someone voted earlier, and retracted and undid their close vote? I guess when the 5th close vote is cast, my manual comment will disappear too.

Comment: (And yes, my own manual "possible duplicate" comment is now deleted. But that's okay, as that was just the same as an automatic comment.)

Comment: Just for the archives: a few manual comments including both "possible duplicate" and some links, [were not touched](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss9tp.png) today [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203566/when-flagging-duplicates-the-auto-posted-comment-should-be-capitalized-correctl).

Comment: You're telling me even the ones without "possible" get deleted? Gah.

Comment: I just saw a comment pointing out a duplicate on *another* site get deleted after a question was closed as a duplicate. That is, a comment that had the word "duplicate" and a link pointing off site. Crazy.

Comment: As a mod, I appreciate this feature -- *if it would just link all the questions as duplicates*! (For reference, [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/87305/98) one user voted to close as duplicate of one question, and later added a second question that fit. Closing the question removed both comments, but only the first link was translated into a duplicate link. I had to add the second one by hand.)

Comment: I agree that'd be good @RaphaelRa, but you'd still lose the important context that usually comes with such comments. It violates the principle of least astonishment. I didn't use the duplicate functionality so why is the duplicate functionality actung on that comment?

Answer (score 7):

### Comments linking to duplicates which were deleted after question closure, despite having other content

Anyone else is welcome to add to the list. If you can link directly to the comment, that's best. Otherwise, link to the question.

**Please note whether the comment was originally auto-generated (via a close vote) or not.**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551665/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-warnings-that-come-from-external-libraries (Auto-generated)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292385/why-i-am-getting-dead-lock-when-execute-nested-dispatch-sync-gcd-objective-c (Auto-generated)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318458/c-sharp-emulator-error-says-to-many-connections (auto-generated comment which I edited was removed).
[Tikz: Arrow description closer to arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130693/tikz-arrow-description-closer-to-arrow) (auto-generated by flagging, not close vote) This was on TeX.SE, but as I understand it, the behavior is network wide.  I didn't realize that then, and asked about it on TeX meta: [why was "possible duplicate" comment with additional information deleted?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/why-was-possible-duplicate-comment-with-additional-) information-deleted

[Not allowed to call release on NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023840/not-allowed-to-call-release-on-nsstring) (Auto-generated)

[Answering a duplicate question with a more current answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202900/answering-on-a-duplicate-answer-but-with-a-more-current-answer#comment645695_202900) (Auto-generated)

[Could someone implement a real logout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210629/could-someone-implement-a-real-logout#comment675731_210629) (Auto-generated)

[Better way to frame "which is better" and "which is the best" type questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211323/better-way-to-frame-which-is-better-and-which-is-the-best-type-questions#comment679071_211323) (Auto-generated)

[Why would you post answers to stupid questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223849/why-would-you-post-answers-to-stupid-questions#comment729879_223849) (Auto-generated)

Answer (score 2):

This is the opposite situation: a "possible duplicate" comment that was added by hand after having deleted the auto-generated comment. This comment is identical to the generated one, but has survived closure:

[Converting string to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320930/converting-string-to-nsdate#comment26888789_18320930)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495501/how-can-i-draw-a-rotated-string-in-2d) I also added the "possible duplicate" comment myself, after I was the first to vote to close, as no comment appeared after my vote. (Maybe someone voted earlier, and retracted their close vote and deleted their automatic comment?) After the 5th close vote was cast, my manual comment was still deleted. (Which is fine in this case, but which does not match what Josh reported in this very answer.)

Answer (score 1):

> A user just posted his question a second time here on meta after the first was closed as a duplicate. I wrote a comment on the second post, explaining that the answer to his question is in the linked duplicate and that he **shouldn't circumvent** the closure process **by asking a second** identical question.

One reason this happens might be that when a question is closed as a duplicate this text appears:

> "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. **If** those answers do not **fully** address your question, please **ask a new question**.".

Perhaps the text should be lengthened and mention that they should explain in subsequent questions why/how their new question does not duplicate any existing questions.