# Could someone implement a real logout?

Tags: feature-request, logout

*Apologies for my posting tone, but I'm leaving this computer now and wanted to make clear that there's a problem. Note that I didn't use the incognito mode when logged into my Open-ID provider because of some SO-unrelated issues with it.*

Logging out of SO has always puzzled me. The recent change might be an improvement, though the logout link keeps to be hidden nearly as hard as before. Nonetheless I see I've been smart enough to find it (shouldn't I get a golden badge for this hard work?) and logged out of SO.

The sad thing is that I'm still logged in here on meta. You can argue it's a different site, but seriously:

- Is it?
- Should we care?
- Does it make any sense to log out of one sub-site and stay logged in in the others?

An answer like "[it can't be done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109293/155925)" is non-sense. In addition to the fact that that Google does it, I'd say that it's pretty easily doable (make the cookie dependent of a counter incremented on each logout or whatever, the crypto site guys surely know better).

In similar questions I've seen, the answers seem to miss some problems:

- There should be a *real global* logout, which means

  - it should log you out of all SO sites
  - no matter if you've failed to use the incognito mode
  - no matter if the browser supports it
  - no matter if the cookies get backed up somewhere in the meantime
  - no matter on *how many devices* you logged in

*Simply tell the server that all the current cookies are invalid. That simple, really.*

Comment: You could possibly use the Stack Exchange API to build a userscript that gets a list of all accounts for that user, then systematically builds logout urls for them and then pings those urls.

Comment: @jmort253: I possibly could. But the server *surely* could increment a single counter and this way invalidate all current sessions.

Comment: I must admit I've never understood the openID thing, it seems to offer zero benefits and all these problems

Comment: @RichardTingle: I wouldn't say it's OpenId's fault. It makes the logging in much more comfortable for the price of some problems. It's the logging out on SO what sucks a lot and this is rather unrelated. A part of the problem is SO being actually a single site pretending it is not.

Comment: @maaartinus possibly this is a separate problem but there is also the "you log out,  openID logs you back in" issue

Comment: @RichardTingle: Agreed, but this is something I can live with... when I forget to log out from my OpenId provider, then I really needn't care about SO (my OpenId provider is Google and this is much more important for me).