# Specify again which Community bot process deleted a question

Tags: feature-request, community-user, post-notices

In the days of yore (i.e. before last Monday or so), on questions deleted automatically deleted by Community, one could see which process caused it to be deleted, e.g. RemoveDeadAbandonedQuestions. However, now it doesn't say that.

These reasons were nice; on [the help page](https://web.archive.org/web/20191207054821/https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) one can look for the specific reason to see which thing deleted the post and why, and it was just overall nice to have at least a wee bit of (vague) info about what the Community user was deleting questions for.

**Can we get the ability to see these again?** It was nice to have more info than that a thing deleted the post and a link to a whole big article.

Comment: Per the consensus [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330810/should-meta-requests-be-closed-as-duplicates-of-announcements-if-the-same-thing), voting to close this as a duplicate of [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide).

Comment: @Sonic how is it "consensus" that you posted a -5 score question which has a 2 score accepted answer?

Comment: The question only expresses a neutral point of view, while the answer, which advocates for closing them as duplicates, has a net positive score.

Comment: @Sonic no. The votes on the question are definitely about whether or not the proposal are good.

Comment: Stormblessed, true. Not near a "consensus". See [The Announcement Tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290662/282094), near the bottom of the question. The "Announcement + Discussion" tag used by an employee (especially with a specific statement requesting "Feedback") means that '*answers*' can be offered as "feedback" to the '*question*' (announcement). So, *usually* you would post the above question as an "answer" there (the *dupe link*) ***except***, in *this* case Sonic has already filed a report - which makes this **no less** a duplicate of that link, with the answer already given there.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog and the answer, too is at +7- 5, not really a consensus. Initially, I only downvoted the question to express disagreement with the premise. I have now, seeing the talk about consensus, extended that to the answer. That's not something I like to do, please don't put people in that position by saying there's a consensus when there isn't.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica Ah, I assumed the downvotes on the question were simply because people thought it was a bad discussion that wasn't worth having, not because people disagree with the premise, since it wasn't a feature request. Also, I'm sorry that I mis-phrased it as a consensus in my initial comment; my goal was to vote for it as a dupe and edit in a link to the prior discussion where (in my view) a majority of people agreed with such closures.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the original post featured a disagreement against closing such questions as dupes, but I edited it out and made the question neutral because people were downvoting that initial revision, and I thought those downvotes were against that opinion and people thought they should still be closed. (TL;DR: I misunderstood the consensus of the community. The vote wasn't based on my personal opinion, but on what I thought was the community's opinion. I generally try to uphold it even if it's out of alignment with mine.)