# Closing 'own' question leaves a nonsensical comment

Tags: bug, status-deferred, comments, vote-to-close, information-display

> [image: Screenshot of the "Does this answer your question" auto-comment]
>   ([Comment link](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73748/what-plane-has-the-widest-range-in-speed-in-which-it-can-operate?noredirect=1#comment192870_73748); it was not auto-deleted as suggested in a comment)

Notice the color of the username's background. It is the question asker. When closing own question, the new auto-comment does not make sense.

It is unrelated to [New duplicate automatic comment makes literally zero sense when voting to close as a duplicate of an unanswered question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340009/392799), which is about unanswered questions.

In my humble opinion, the older "possible duplicate" served as a *notice* that worked regardless of who posted it.

On a related note: Community ♦ still being shown as a voter in *this case* can be confusing to new users who just got the close rep.

> [image]
>   (Same post; note: *my* vote was not a duplicate vote, so there wasn't an auto-comment from me)

Comment: Yeah, that comment crashes and burns

Comment: But it should be around for no more then a few seconds, if the OP accepts the dupe closure it should get auto deleted

Comment: @Luuklag: it's not deleted, [here it is](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73748/what-plane-has-the-widest-range-in-speed-in-which-it-can-operate?noredirect=1#comment192870_73748).