# Filter HNQ by site

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

[This feature has been requested before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225297/231156), but it was put on ice eight years ago and appears to have been kan-bandoned by SE. I want to filter certain sites (e.g., Politics) from my HNQ.

Comment: Related: [How do I get attention for a bug report or feature request that was deferred a long time ago?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357341/377214)

Comment: As long as past feature request has not been declined, any same request is duplicate. To bump existing request don't re-ask it, you can edit, place a bounty, etc. And even when it's declined and you want the team to re-consider, posting the exact same thing won't work, you have to explain what has changed over time that the team should reconsider the decision.

Comment: Politics SE isn’t *that* bad...