# Accepted top meta/network posts aren't green colored in the profile

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, accepted-answer, top-network-posts

[My profile link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7881859).

Most "top meta posts" and "top network posts" are accepted but they're not green colored like the "top posts" are.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Now live: A fully responsive profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370964/now-live-a-fully-responsive-profile)

Comment: @Luuklag This post certainly is not a duplicate of the mentioned post.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to this question, but **possibly** a reason why on MSO is that they don't want to [promote that the meta post's answer is actually "correct"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302484/why-can-the-person-asking-the-question-on-meta-choose-what-answer-is-correct/303214#comment237415_303214), or lead anyone to such a false conclusion.

Comment: @WenfangDu it's common to write bug reports as *answers* to a recent announcement post, not as separate questions. See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330810/295232 Otherwise, we risk flooding the home page with dozens of bug reports ...

Comment: @Rob If you see my [MSO profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7881859/wenfang-du?tab=profile), the "top network posts" [are not green colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln4z2.png) too, which conflicts with your mentioned reason.

Comment: @WenfangDu (and whoever upvoted your comment), no there is no conflict - that is exactly what you are being told; not the opposite.

Comment: @Glorfindel but this got nothing to do with responsive design. So can't see how it' can be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 the responsive desgn rewrite changed the formatting of these posts so they are displayed in the same way as top posts. Prior to that rewrite this was not an issue.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 well, the difference is that with the new design, the Meta posts are shown in a similar way as site posts. So one could consider this as a flaw of the new design.

Comment: hmm so that's a totally new bug that isn't related to page being responsive. Weird, but I see now. Still won't close as dupe, think it should get its own report. Chances of it being fixed bit higher. (0.0008% instead of 0.0006% ;-))

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 yeah, maybe, that's why I'm not using a hammer here. I'm just explaining why other users vote to close as a duplicate :)