# Closing a question with multiple duplicates

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Is it possible for a single user to cast a duplicate close vote on a question with more than one duplicate?

Sometimes, more than one question seems like a good candidate for a duplicate close vote. However, the Stack Exchange system allows a single user to specify precisely one post as the duplicate, while different user(s) can specify separate questions as duplicate, and if the original question indeed gets closed as duplicate, all the various duplicates get mentioned.

Is there a way for a single user to specify more than one duplicate, while still getting counted as a single close vote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indicating multiple duplicates is possible, but only if you have a gold tag badge and the corresponding 'dupehammer'. That will allow you to [edit the list of duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/295232) (after it is closed, but that's automatic because of the dupehammer). The dupehammer is still a single close vote, but it's a 'binding' one, just like moderator close votes.

Other users can only post additional links in the form of comments, which you'd have to craft yourself; there's no option to automatically add a second "Possible duplicate of" comment. Alternatively, edit the first one (if it's yours) to include a second original question. It won't be deleted when the question gets closed eventually; this is a [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321882/295232).

Thanks @Sonic for mentioning another option:

> You can also ask in the comments for someone else to vote to close for that other target, and hope someone will: if two different people vote for two different targets, both will be shown.

Comment: You can also ask in the comments for someone else to vote to close for that other target, and hope someone will: if two different people vote for two different targets, both will be shown.

Comment: Thanks. I would have called that 'social engineering' ten years ago, but this term has gained a lot of negative connotations meanwhile.