# How to get Benefactor badge on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges

How do you get the Benefactor badge on Stack Overflow?
First bounty you manually awarded on your own question?

Comment: You seem to be jumping into the whole badges thing without having much of an understanding of the site. Read up on [what bounties even are](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) and you'll understand how to achieve the badge.

Comment: @VishnuKanwar "How do you get the Benefactor badge" "How to put a 'bounty' on a question" The site has NUMEROUS duplicate questions for these, and a WEALTH of info in the about and help pages. Have a read through the site's info and other questions, the info is usually there already. Maybe you didn't know about the "similar posts" that pop up when you start writing a question? When typing your title to this question in a new question form, it brings up a list of quite relevant duplicate questions for you to read underneath the title :)

Comment: I can't believe they deleted my comment.  This is not a dupe.  This is a specific question, and shouldn't be closed as a dupe of the general question, but of another specific one if there is one.

Comment: @LanceRoberts you might want to read [Possible Duplicate comment deletion is over-zealous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195652/possible-duplicate-comment-deletion-is-over-zealous) - things that look like duplicate comments appear to get deleted when the question is duped.

Comment: @LanceRoberts based solely on precise definition I agree this is not a dupe of those linked to, however I think the basic point is that this question is not necessary at all. There is plenty of info about this exact thing that is *very easy* to find with *very little* effort required. It has many direct dupes, and similar dupes. The ones chosen above as dupes could perhaps have been chosen better, but they lead to relevant info and why spend time on a question as poor as this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put a bounty on a question you posted.  When you award the bounty to an answer yourself (not allowing it to be automatically awarded), then you'll get the badge (with some time delay).

Comment: How to put a 'bounty' on a question?

Comment: You have to wait a day or two after you ask the question before you can put a bounty on it.  Then there'll be a link to post the bounty.

Comment: @VishnuKanwar: first you'll need 75 reputation. But do you actually have a question you want to bring attention to, or do you just want a badge?

Comment: @Wooble: I have a question to bring attention to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269438/is-there-a-way-to-call-member-function-without-operator