# Additional comments for 'possible duplicate' disappearing

Tags: bug, comments, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Sometimes I find more than one good candidate to close a question as a duplicate of.

In this case I vote to close once, and post the other candidates as separate comments, exactly in the form of the auto-generated comment ("possible duplicate of [title](link)").

If the answer is consenquently closed as duplicate, my manually posted comments would get picked up and become a part of the gray duplicate box on top of the question.
Sometimes they wouldn't, but in this case they would stay under the question in the form of comments, which is also okay.

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21690605/11683), however, my three comments comments were deleted, but only one made it to the gray box (so I even lost track of the question, because it was no longer on my Activity page).

Is this intended?

Comment: Pretty sure all "possible duplicate" comments are deleted, even if that link wasn't one of the selected duplicates. It would only get picked up by the grey box if someone actually chose that one as the duplicate.

Comment: The interaction of close votes and "possible duplicate" comments is inscrutable at best. See [Possible duplicate comment deletion is over zealous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195652), [Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141414), [Does voting to close as duplicate erase earlier comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130864), and, if you're over 10k [Closing as duplicate removes links that point to other duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89279) (no idea why that's been deleted).