# Why does data.StackExchange show only 1 reputation

Tags: support, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why are my SEDE results inaccurate/obsolete/incorrect/outdated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/why-are-my-sede-results-inaccurate-obsolete-incorrect-outdated)

I just went to `data.StackExchange` and [tried top users in Singapore Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71527/top-users-singapore), I didn't see my name in the first half of the list, in fact my name appears as 984

[image]

and then I modified and ran this query, thinking may be it is not picking up correctly, so provide the username.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [#], 
    Id AS [User Link], 
    Reputation
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    (LOWER(Location) LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR UPPER(Location) LIKE '%SG') AND DisplayName = 'mprabhat'
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

Result shows I have just 1 reputation, Why ?

[image]

Comment: I can't provide an answer, but I can tell you this: data.stackexchange rarely give accurate responses.

Comment: Oh I see, I dont remember but some user from Singapore had mentioned this, I looked at his profile and then came to data.stackExchange :), thanks anyway

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and blame @[BoltClock♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) for this. ;)

Comment: Did you happen to be suspended when the last data dump happened (May 7th)?  Because it shows lots of upvotes, but the 1 rep makes me think a suspension was active at the time of the export (also you have a gap in posts from May 2nd to May 9th, which also seems like a 1 week suspension).

Comment: Yeah I was suspended for 1 week, so this is not real time data rather dump

Comment: Precisely.  If you look in the "duplicate" I linked to, you'll see that it's updated roughly every month / couple of months.

Comment: I did a search for data.stackexchange didn't do the data explorer search or else would have gotten that link:)

Comment: Ha, no problem =)  It's almost inevitable that one misses something while searching.