# How to track users having highest number of a specific badge

Tags: discussion, badges, data-explorer

There are some badges which can be awarded multiple times, like [Great Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/great-answer).

Is there any option to identify the users who have been awarded a specific badge (e.g. Great Answer) the most times?

Comment: data query challenged dropped ... who will accept it??

Comment: Just a guess at [a guy with 5934 badge](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges).

Comment: I don't meant the complete number of badges, but the guy with the highest number of a specific badge, like notable question badge, that can be awarded multiple times.

Comment: Maybe it isn't a guy...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for this!

[Who has earned a specific badge the most times?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77471/who-has-earned-a-specific-badge-the-most-times?BadgeName=Great+Answer)

Input the badge name you're interested in in the text box.

Here's the "Great Answer" badge results:

[image: Top earners of the "Great Answer" badge]

Note that you're results won't be 100% up to date.  See here: [Why are my SEDE results inaccurate/obsolete/incorrect/outdated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/why-are-my-sede-results-inaccurate-obsolete-incorrect-outdated)

Comment: Wow.  Jon Skeet has earned more Nice Answer badges in the time since the SEDE results were last updated than I've earned total badges ever.

Comment: @AdamRackis If it makes you feel any better, Jon skeet has more badges than I have reputation points on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

The question didn't explicitly ask for this, but it's possible to check who has the greatest number of Great Answer badges *across the network*.

The answer, according to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1368236/users-having-the-highest-number-of-a-specific-badge-networkwide?badgename=Great+Answer), is still Jon Skeet:

[image]

Comment: Updated SEDE query by GlorfindelMod showing the max number of badges earned in a single site: 
https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1604707/holders-of-a-specific-badge-networkwide-sorted-by-total?badgename=Great%20Answer