# Query returns wrong result

Tags: support, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why are my SEDE results inaccurate/obsolete/incorrect/outdated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/why-are-my-sede-results-inaccurate-obsolete-incorrect-outdated)

I've run the following query, just to see if it actually works, but I'm getting no results even though I have dozens of posts:

```
select
  q.Id
from
  Posts q
where
  q.OwnerUserId = 1525840
```

What's going wrong? I'm executing the query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

Comment: Could you be more specific than "doesn't work"?

Comment: More specific than "*getting no results even though I have dozens of posts*"? Not sure how to make it clearer...

Comment: @Chamster I wrote that, after he commented. You wrote "I've run the following query, just to see if it actually works. Well, it doesn't."

Comment: @MichaelMrozek True, so true... I'll be in my corner wearing a hat of shame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SEDE data isn't live, it comes from periodic data dumps. You can see on [the homepage](https://data.stackexchange.com/) that the most recent data is from June 26th; your first post wasn't made until [July 14th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485697/multiselector-doesnt-execute-animations-simultaneously-in-jquery)