# Can't find myself in the query on Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why are my SEDE results inaccurate/obsolete/incorrect/outdated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/why-are-my-sede-results-inaccurate-obsolete-incorrect-outdated)

The query is about **[Top Indian users in StackOverFlow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81789/top-indian-users-in-stackoverflow)**

But I can't find myself in the query. Can anybody explain why?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148413/187824   http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145697/187824

Comment: For those who don't like naked links, the short version is that SEDE's data can become (and currently are) months out of date, though the team is working on making updates happen weekly.

Comment: Presumably you either changed your name or added your location since the last time the data was updated.

Comment: Ok yes. I just add the location in my profile. so when do you update the SEDE. I mean on what intervel ?

Comment: At the moment is it not being updated, but once updates start again they will hopefully be weekly.

Comment: so how old the data is ?

Comment: Currently it's everything up to June 26th, 2012. You can see the dates [on the front page](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. hope that SEDE get updated soon