# Removed comments not being removed from SEDE database

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, comments, data-explorer

I tried generating obsoletes with [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/157286/obsoletes) SEDE Query, but if you look under the 'Comment Link' row, something is really weird.  Some of the links don't contain the comment in the post anymore (for example, the first row that's always there says 'upvoted', but it doesn't exist when you click the comment link), so I tried running the Stack Exchange API with one of the id's (from the id row), and I get 'bad parameter: comment doesn't exist'.

Does this mean SEDE tables don't get rows removed when comments are deleted?  If so, can this be added, so I can *actually use* SEDE productively?

Another example is that [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/157286/obsoletes) always generates the **same** results, no matter what.

Can we get this fixed?  I have an SE app to be made, and this bug is making things a bunch harder.

Here is an example id generated: 7115887

**Edit**

I found out from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77174/data-from-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-are-obsolete?rq=1) that SEDE is updated weekly, so is there a better way I can generate Stack Exchange SQL Queries to get more updated results, straight from the API?

Comment: Got an example comment ID that gives you this?

Comment: @AnnaLear 7686101, also I found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77174/data-from-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-are-obsolete?rq=1)

Comment: [That comment isn't deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419227/can-oauth-2-0-support-multiple-grants-in-a-single-redirection-journey/6437725#comment7686101_6437725).

Comment: @AnnaLear Oops, wrong id.  Meant: 7115887

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEDE is now updated weekly. I edited the post you link to to reflect this. It's unlikely that it's going to be updated more frequently than that, at least not in the foreseeable future.

The query results on SEDE are also cached and limited to returning at most 50,000 rows. The way your query is written, you're pretty much guaranteed to have the same results for a week, or at least results that look eerily similar unless 50,000+ comments get deleted.

If you need up-to-date information, especially when building an app, using the API is your best bet.

Comment: How would I run SQL queries with the API?

Comment: @ManofSnow Why would you? Just use the API directly and then whatever language you prefer to process the results of your queries.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem, I decided to just use SEDE but make it so it checks if the comment exists, I mean only about 5% are deleted, anyway

Comment: If I do that, then I'll quickly run out of API quota for that user...

Comment: @TheWobbuffet That could be a sign to consider the fact that you may be doing something excessive. ;)

Comment: 50,000 queries should be *almost* enough for a moderator :P