# Obsolete data when using Stack Exchange API

Tags: support, api

*Note:* I've already read [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77174/216721) but this question doesn't talk about the data explorer data(or that's what am guessing). It is about getting the data from the API(more real time).

I was casually browsing around the [documentation of Stack Exchange API v2.2](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) when I happened to stumble upon an api which returns all sites in the network. [This is the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=999&filter=default&run=true) I'm talking about. If you click on that link, it'll fetch a JSON result which contains all the sites available in the network. While going through this data, I found that it has obsolete/wrong data in it.

---

To elaborate more on what am talking about, here are a couple of example(without and with obsolete data).

1. *Without obsolete data*: **Stack Overflow**

   The data in the JSON related to Stack Overflow is as follows(only related):

   Site URL: http://stackoverflow.com

   Aliases: http://www.stackoverflow.com , http://facebook.stackoverflow.com

   The second alias http://facebook.stackoverflow.com is acceptable as it redirects to this URL, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook*.
2. *With obsolete data*: **Meta Stack Overflow**

   The data in the JSON related to Stack Overflow is as follows(only related):

   Site URL: http://meta.stackoverflow.com

   Aliases: http://meta.stackexchange.com , http://bugs.meta.stackoverflow.com

   Here the first alias properly redirects to Meta, but the second URL, http://bugs.meta.stackoverflow.com , gives a **Server not found** error. This is the obsolete data I'm talking about.

I'm of the idea that this URL http://bugs.meta.stackoverflow.com **probably used** to redirect to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug but it doesn't do that anymore and the dev folks forgot to remove it from their database.

But in case it never used to redirect it to Meta, why is this URL returned in the JSON in the aliases for Meta Stack Overflow? In any case, shouldn't this data be done away with or is there a history behind having this data which I'm unaware of.