# User details are not correct in the Stack Overflow DB table User

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I just tried to write a simple [select query to get user details](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/341550/get-user-details).

And the result is not correct. For SO it displays the reputation count less than what it is now. And the last access date is `2015-02-04 06:57:45` , but I'm using it regularly. My `SO id` is `2523147`. And some fields are not updated yet.

Why is this? Are those not the original current data?

Comment: No repro. For user id 2523147 it yields last access 2015-07-24 which is correct since database is refreshed once a week.

Comment: @DeerHunter : try switching the sites using `Switch sites: ` . Select SO in that. just click on the SO icon. then it display that date I mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, you are looking at results for Meta Stack Overflow. Please check the address bar.

Comment: @Dronehinge That's relevant, but overall this looks like a bad query *on top* of that, so not really a duplicate. I'd post an answer and get some free meta rep if I were you. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the Stack Overflow [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/341550/get-user-details?id=2523147) and here is the Meta Stack Overflow [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/341550/get-user-details?id=2523147). *Notice how the url says which site you are running the query for.* So looks like the date was so outdated because you were actually viewing the Meta SO instead of SO. The rep is the same on Meta SO and SO.

Yes, the date is still outdated as of your last access date for the SO query, since it shows 7/24/15 even though you've been on today, this is because the data is [only updated once a week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77174/data-from-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-is-obsolete) in SEDE (On Sunday Morning around 5 AM UTC). Same for why it shows 874 reputation instead of the 919 you now have. Since you had 874 rep when it last updated.

Comment: that's clear. thank you