# Is there a way to programmatically get the days 'visited' information?

Tags: support, status-completed, api, so-enterprise

On our Stack Overflow for Teams: Enterprise instance, I'd like to use the API to build a report on how often users visit the site. I can see this information in the admin dashboard (e.g. below, "visited 43 days, 1 consecutive"):

> [image]

Is there a way to get the days visited information with the API?

Comment: via the API - don't think so, that'll be a surprise to me if it's possible. the `User` interfsce does not return that information.

Comment: @SteveDunn Given that you're saying this question is explicitly about Stack Overflow for Teams: Enterprise, then removing that tag is not correct.

Comment: However, support for Stack Overflow for Teams: Enterprise is not provided through any of the Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow Meta sites, because the Enterprise product includes dedicated support, and, importantly, because the people on SO/SE Meta sites just don't have access to the Enterprise product, which is different, at least in some characteristics (so, volunteers on the public products, who are the ones typically answering questions on Meta sites, often can't accurately answer such questions).

Comment: Support for Stack Overflow for Teams: Business and Enterprise products is first first within your organization and then to dedicated staff inside Stack Overflow (rather than the volunteers on the public sites, who are the ones normally answering on Meta sites). You can contact Stack Overflow staff directly through the [Support Portal](https://stackenterprise.freshdesk.com/support/tickets/new). Stack Overflow also gives their Stack Overflow for Teams: Business and Enterprise Support Portal link as [this shortened URL](https://s.tk/support).

Comment: For public sites: The information which you are looking for is *not* directly available from the SE API for public sites. You can get information about when the user last accessed the site. You can also get a considerable amount of information about the user's public actions, from which you can determine at least a portion of when the user was visiting. However, that won't give you actual visited information for any day the user didn't perform a public action. There may be more information available from the SPI on SO for Teams: Enterprise, but I don't know.

Comment: Please contact support@stackoverflow.com for help with Stack Overflow Enterprise.

Comment: @Juice you picked wrong close reason. Now it says "This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network" which implies Stack Overflow for Teams is not related in any way to Stack Exchange, which I assume is wrong, unless SE sold it to a different company? Anyhow, there is special close reason exactly for those cases: No longer reproducible, can you please reopen and close with correct reason?

Answer (score 1):

Feature requests for the API can be filled here: [What would you want to see in a Stack Overflow API?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12224/282094)

The Team's API Help is here:   https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams and the "user object" help is here:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user

So to query your "last accessed " on Stack Overflow you'd use this query: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=Makyen&filter=default&site=stackoverflow

Which returns this value:

```
{
  "badge_counts": {
    "bronze": 87,
    "silver": 61,
    "gold": 11
  },
  "account_id": 14162,
  "is_employee": false,
  "last_modified_date": 1667471400,
  "last_access_date": 1668964887,
  "reputation_change_year": 999,
  "reputation_change_quarter": 182,
  "reputation_change_month": 112,
  "reputation_change_week": 0,
  "reputation_change_day": 0,
  "reputation": 20364,
  "creation_date": 1224248153,
  "user_type": "registered",
  "user_id": 28901,
  "accept_rate": 77,
  "location": "United Kingdom",
  "website_url": "http://blog.dunnhq.com",
  "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/28901/steve-dunn",
  "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/754672131bf84b01ef8294606d8e4190?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG",
  "display_name": "Steve Dunn"
},
```

The [date](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates): 1668987171 is "unix epoch time", which translates to: "GMT: Sunday, November 20, 2022 5:21:27 PM".

An exact value for "last_access_date" was removed from the profile due to privacy issues: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368289/282094 - it is unlikely that they would add back the ability with an API update, but the post for making a feature request is the first URL in this answer.

It is also possible to access the "last_access_date" using SEDE: "https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261689/282094", but while such information is collected daily, it is only updated once a week, making a true determination of the last accessed date problematic; you need more than a single API call, unless you use an external service.

You can check using Stack Exchange's API, and if the "last_access_date" is more than one day then they don't have consecutive days. If it is less than one day then you would need to return on Sunday (after SEDE's database is updated) to check the total number of days; only accumulating a week long database of particular users if you need an up to date record of their consecutive days.

Note that there are many screenscraping services that offer an API interface, so it's easy enough to create an URL that accesses the information on demand, programmatically.

There's not a single API call that provides this restricted information, it is partially privacy protected.

As to the question asked by your title:

> "Is there a way to programmatically get the days 'visited' information?"

Yes. You can use one of three ways to view days visited, consecutive days, and the last date and time visited.

Comment: The question asks for the *visited days* information, *not* the `last_access_date`. In other words, the question is asking for how many days the user visited the site, how many consecutive days, and, potentially, a list of days the user visited. On public sites, the list of days is, effectively, provided to each user via the calendar showing the days they accessed the site. I don't know if that calendar information is available through the normal UI to Admin users on a Stack Overflow for Teams: Enterprise instance. That information isn't in what you're suggesting they obtain from the SE API.

Comment: Last time I know, "last access date" can change without "visited" being updated, [since the users need to do more than accessing the site for the purpose of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485/241919).

Comment: @Rob, If what you are proposing the user do is to create their own database and accumulate statistics on every user in order to develop their own database of visited days, then you really should state that in your answer.