# How can it be possible that my capped reputation is higher than uncapped reputation?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, data-explorer

### Note:

The [uncapped rep query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/2868/how-high-would-my-reputation-approximately-be-when-there-was-no-cap-or-cw#resultSets) that I use here is included in a [META SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49943/3834), which itself is referenced by [a SE blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/06/learn-more-about-your-site-with-the-se-data-explorer-heres-how/?cb=1). This should say a lot about the importance and the correctness of the query.

### Problem:

**My uncapped reputation (35051) as shown in data explorer must be higher than my current reputation (35130 as of 24/6/2016), but it is not. The current uncapped rep query doesn't take into account of the bounties and downvotes on answers, so my actual uncapped rep should be lower, which means that either the data source at data explorer or the SO reputation system is erroneous**

My [current reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3834/graviton) on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) is 35130.

[image]

But my uncapped reputation, according to [data explorer is 35051](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/2868/how-high-would-my-reputation-approximately-be-when-there-was-no-cap-or-cw#resultSets).

[image]

So it seems that after my reputation is capped, it becomes higher! How can this *ever* be possible?

I understand that the [data explorer data is updated on weekly basis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77176/3834), so I probably should make sure that my reputation on stackoverflow.com one week ago is less than the uncapped reputation in data explorer.

So I check [my reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3834/graviton?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2015-10-15%2008:22:23Z):

[image]

and I find that I gain 78 rep points since 17 June 2016, which means that my capped rep on 17 June 2016 is 35130-78=**35052**. Still higher than the uncapped rep at data explorer (**35051**) by 1 point.

Not only that, I [hit the 200 reputation cap at least once](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard?userid=3834).

[image]

This is the query:

```
-- How high would my reputation approximately be when there was no cap or CW?

DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
      WHEN VoteTypeId = 1 THEN 15 -- Accepted answer.
      WHEN VoteTypeId = 2 AND PostTypeId = 1 THEN 5 -- Upvoted question
      WHEN VoteTypeId = 2 AND PostTypeId = 2 THEN 10 -- Upvoted answer.
      WHEN VoteTypeId = 3 THEN -2 -- Downvote.
      WHEN VoteTypeId = 9 THEN BountyAmount -- Earned Bounty
END) AS UncappedReputation
FROM
    Votes
  INNER JOIN 
    Posts ON Posts.Id = Votes.PostId
WHERE
    Posts.OwnerUserId = @UserId
```

### What about point changes that are not captured by this query?

As pointed out by several commenters and [an answerer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280590/3834), this query doesn't take into account of:

1. The bounties that I gave away
2. My downvote on answers
3. The reputation received for suggested edit when my reputation was below 2,000

3. is not applicable in my case because that feature came in after I was not eligible for reputation from it.

As for the first two, if they were taken into account, as they are deducting points away from my rep, *my uncapped reputation would be lower* than what I have currently.

So if this query is more complete, then my uncapped reputation would be lower, which compounds rather than solves the problem.

**My conclusion is that there must be something wrong with either the data source at data explorer, or the SO reputation system, which SO team should look into.**

Comment: Doesn't every user start with a rep of 1 which is the difference between your two reps?

Comment: You never reached the cap, so this query is totally not relevant for you.

Comment: The query says "approximately". I doubt it can take, e.g., your downvotes on answers into account. Also, the query is just some random dude's work: it's not even slightly official.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, oh yes. I did hit the cap, at least once. See the updated question

Comment: @PolyGeo, that initial rep of 1 is both accounted for in the capped and uncapped rep. So it's not an explaining factor

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy, the sql query is official enough to be included in a [META SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49943/3834), which itself is official enough to be quoted by a SE  [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/06/learn-more-about-your-site-with-the-se-data-explorer-heres-how/?cb=1).

Comment: @Graviton:: The question is called "*interesting* queries", not "*totally accurate* queries", and is referred to the same way in the blog post. That's because it's interesting, and helpful, but there is absolutely no indication that it's anything other than some random dude's idea of how to get some cool stats.

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy, you are welcome to look at the query to see whether it does everything right. It's a simple query and I do think it is correct.

Comment: Well, the query does not take into account bounties you have offered, which is over 1000 rep in your case. All in all, that query **is not accurate** and IMO should not be given as example in that blog post or the tutorial. (at least not with clear message saying it's not accurate)

Comment: @Graviton: I've used the query in the past. It's probably as good as it can get. Unfortunately, it is *inherently and unavoidably* wrong, which is why it has the disclaimer. It doesn't include answer downvotes, and can't, and won't.

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy, I thought it does include downvote answers? Look at the part  `WHEN VoteTypeId = 3 THEN -2 -- Downvote.`

Comment: @Graviton: It doesn't include *your* downvotes, which are -1 each, just downvotes from *others*, which are -2.

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy, my downvotes should take points further away from my uncapped rep, if taken into account, see the updated question

Comment: @ShadowWizard, see updated question. The offered bounties should take more points away from my uncapped rep, which means that my uncapped rep is actually even lower than its current level, which means that it is more incorrect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will note the SQL comment at the top of the query you posted:

```
-- How high would my reputation approximately be when there was no cap or CW?
```

Key word here is **approximately**.

Bounties that you have given away are not included in this query (drops of between 50-500, in increments of 50).

You have [offered 1,100 reputation in bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3834/graviton?tab=bounties&sort=offered) (at this point in time).

Nor are your downvotes on answers included - each would reduce your reputation by 1.

So, there is **at least** 1,100 in your reputation that is not accounted for.

Additionally, deleted posts are not in SEDE, even though they might cause some reputation to be retained on the site - specifically, posts with a score of 3 or more that have been deleted 60 days or more after being posted. This reputation will be retained by yourself, but will not exist in SEDE.

This [query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3A1%20user%3A3834%20score%3A3..) (need +10k rep to see the results) shows 21 such posts at this time, which account for ~1,800 reputation that will not be in SEDE.

---

There is also reputation received for suggested edits which is not accounted for in that query, but that feature came in *after* you were already not eligible for reputation from it (you had over 2,000 reputation at that point).

Comment: my uncapped rep would be lower if the omitted point change source is taken into account, which compounds rather than solves the problem. See the updated question

Comment: Oded, would you mind checking @Graviton's account for deleted 60+-day old posts with 3+ score? Those would presumably not be included in the query, but are of course included in rep.

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy, I don't recall deleting any posts since I ever join SO, but you are more than welcome to check

Comment: @Graviton: Yes, well, nobody ever does recall that. I don't have 10k on SO and it wouldn't do me any good if I did; only mods can see *lists* of old deleted posts.

Comment: @Graviton please visit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=deleted%3a1). What do you see?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I do see a very long list of my deleted questions. But what does this mean? I know that the reputation at SO ( capped rep) doesn't consider these questions to be adding to my rep in general, but what about the reputation at data explorer? If it doesn't, then it won't explain the rep diff, if it does consider, and because I receive mostly upvotes and upvotes carry more points than downvotes, then my actual uncapped rep from the data explorer is *even* lower. It doesn't explain the discrepancy at all.

Comment: @Graviton Post with a score of 3+ that was deleted after 60 days retains the earned reputation, yet you won't see it in SEDE. So for example, if old answer you had with 10 upvotes got deleted, it means 100 reputation you'll see on the site but not in SEDE.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, what about -ve posts that were deleted after 60 days?

Comment: @Graviton if the post score was less than 3, the rep is gone. (e.g. answer with only 2 upvotes will reduce 20 rep, no matter when deleted)