# Is the Data Explorer now updated weekly?

Tags: data-explorer, support

There was an update around the 17th or 18th. Now, I see that all of the sites have been updated as of the 25th. I know that there was a time when a weekly or every-two-week update cycle was planned, but I couldn't find any confirmation of this having been implemented.

The [Data Explorer FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq) still says monthly, but there had been a delay of a few months at one point, so I'm not entirely sure that the FAQ is trustworthy on all points.

Every other post that I've found about the Data Explorer is at least a few months old, and this appears to be a recent change.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yeah, [Nick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) put this together [the other week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data/145732#145732). The process is fully automated now, and runs on a weekly basis. The dates on the front page now also reflect the last update date of the data (instead of before, when they reflected the date of the latest content at the time of the update).

I'll make a note to update the FAQ, unless someone else wants to [contribute a change](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/) before I get to it.

Comment: Yep, confirming this is the case - I get a email every Sunday morning around 5am letting me know it ran okay, if not then I'll hop on and fix it...so far so good!

Comment: Always nice when a plan comes together without raging fires and a sense of impending doom!

Comment: @NickCraver, Is it still 5am now?