# Why is the number of views different in data.se.com compared with the number on the actual question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer

I wrote a quick query to find out the most viewed question on the electronics SE but the views are different. For example here:

> Good Tools for Drawing Schematics | 9876

While if you visit the [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/good-tools-for-drawing-schematics) it says it has:

> VIEWED **10018 TIMES**

So why is there a difference? Here is the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/91765/most-viewed-question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data in the data explorer is not real-time.

It gets [updated weekly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156709/is-the-data-explorer-now-updated-weekly), so you can expect such a discrepancy.