# How do I search for non-deleted questions in data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, search, data-explorer

I tried to filter for questions that have not been deleted.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/953463/non-deleted-posts

However, the top result shows

```
Post Link                                                           deletiondate closeddate          
------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------ ------------------- 
Should I learn "Legacy Spring", or just jump to Spring Boot         null         null
```

It shows `null` for deletiondate, yet [the question was deleted 13 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901383/should-i-learn-legacy-spring-or-just-jump-to-spring-boot-given-the-direction).

> deleted by LightCC 13 hours ago

So how do I only display questions that are not deleted?

```
select top 1000 p.id as [Post Link], p.deletiondate, p.closeddate
from posts p
where p.answercount = 0
order by p.creationdate desc
```

Comment: Also, same issue as: [Why is the number of views different in data.se.com compared with the number on the actual question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163417/why-is-the-number-of-views-different-in-data-se-com-compared-with-the-number-on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong. SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning (UTC); see the [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq). In a few days, this question will be removed from the `Posts` table and you won't be bothered by it anymore.